# How to convert string "1," to decimal?(C#)

Tags: c#, string, type-conversion, decimal

I have the following string

```
string str = "1,"
```

How do I convert it to decimal `1.00`? I use it in this code:

```
EditText quantityEditText = FindViewById<EditText>(Resource.Id.quantityEditText);
quantityEditText.SetFilters(new IInputFilter[] { new DecimalFilter(3) });
quantityEditText.TextChanged += (object sender, Android.Text.TextChangedEventArgs e) => {
    //calculate total price and set it to totalPriceTextView
    decimal articlePriceAfterDiscount = Convert.ToDecimal(articlePriceAfterDiscountTextView.Text);
    decimal articleQuantity = Convert.ToDecimal(e.Text.ToString());
    decimal totalPrice = Math.Round(articlePriceAfterDiscount * articleQuantity,2);
    totalPriceTextView.Text = totalPrice.ToString();
};
```

So when typing `1,` I don't get error.

Comment: The line `decimal articleQuantity = Convert.ToDecimal(e.Text.ToString());` is already converting a string to a decimal. What are you actually having problems with? And you say "So I don't get an error" but dont' actually tell us what error you are getting... Please provide us with a MCVE (https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) so we can better understand your problem.

Comment: I was surprise to find that `Android.Text.TextChangedEventArgs.Text` is actually `IEnumerabl<char>` instead of a `string`.  So calling `ToString` on that is not going to do what you want.  You'll have to do somethind like `new string(e.Text.ToArray())` instead.

Comment: When I type `1,` I get error in `articleQuantity` variable saing it's not a number

Comment: @Profile3ForStack That's because calling `ToString` on a `IEnumerable<char>` might not give you the actual string depending on the underlying type that's returned.  For instance if it returns a `char[]` then you'll get `System.Char[]` instead of "1,".  So check that first.

Comment: @Profile3ForStack: Well what is the value of `e.Text.ToString()`?

Comment: This is a really really bad idea to implement. it would take heavy Regex parsing and will be error prone. You have to take care of culture and thousands and decimal separators when doing something like this. Whatever you do, think of at least these tests: 1,000,122.3 ;
1300 ;
1.300,2 ;
1 300. ;
1 3 0 2.1 ;
1. ;
1., ;
1,00.3 ;
1,000.3 ;
1,000.3,2 ;
1

Answer (score 2):

The information provided by [@juharr](https://stackoverflow.com/users/302918/juharr) in his comment:

> I was surprise to find that `Android.Text.TextChangedEventArgs.Text` is actually `IEnumerabl<char>` instead of a `string`

Led me to read the [documentation of the Android.Text.TextChangedEventArgs Class](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/type/Android.Text.TextChangedEventArgs/)

It shows clearly the the property [Text](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/property/Android.Text.TextChangedEventArgs.Text/) is of the following type:

> `public IEnumerable<char> Text { get; }`

So I would suggest the following solution. It uses this nice [string constructor overload](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ttyxaek9(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
decimal articleQuantity = Convert.ToDecimal(new string(e.Text.ToArray()));
```

Answer (score 1):

A very basic example (Using C# 7 syntax):

```
using System;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        string toParse = "1";
        if (Decimal.TryParse(toParse, out var parsed)) {
            Console.WriteLine("Parsed: " + parsed.ToString());
        } else {
            Console.WriteLine("Nope");
        }
    }
}
```

The same example using pre-C# 7 syntax:

```
using System;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        string toParse = "1";
        decimal parsed;
        if (Decimal.TryParse(toParse, out parsed)) {
            Console.WriteLine("Parsed: " + parsed.ToString());
        } else {
            Console.WriteLine("Nope");
        }
    }
}
```

The only difference between the two is that C# 7 allows us to instantiate the out parameter on `TryParse` inline, as opposed to outside of the method invocation.

Most type constructs like Decimal, int, long, bool, etc have a `.TryParse` method, which pretty much does what it says on the tin. It will try to parse a value, return a boolean to indicate results and hand back the parsed value if it was successful.

Comment: I’ll suggest to adopt this solution to lower versions of C#. Not everyone has adopted to latest yet.